# End arrow is missing while dragging node in dagre-d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dagre-d3, dagre

I have a simple graph, parent node is polygon and child node is rectangle. There is a edge between those two nodes. Here the problem is once we drag any of the node, the end arrow which is connected to polygon is missing. can any one help me out why that end arrow is missing.
sample fiddle is available in the comments.

Comment: sample Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbxvhx17/145/

Answer (score 1):

End arrow is not missing, per se. It is being hidden behind the polygon. 
add

```
polygon {
  fill: rgba(100,100,100,0.5)
}
```

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/bbxvhx17/153/)

to your css and you will see what's happening.
As for a fix, im not too sure where you went wrong, but it would be with how you calculated where the edge of the shape and line intersect.

[EDIT]: judging by the way the arrow moves around the diamond shape. (it moves around the centre in a diamond shape), it looks like the diamond shape you are drawing and the shape that the code thinks is there, and hence finding the intersection with, dont match up in terms of scale and position

Comment: Its kind of hack, but still works. Thanks for the suggestion, yeah it is moving around the center of the shape. In the fiddle, the intersectPolygon function available in the dagre-d3 file only, `points.push(intersectPolygon(head, polypoints, points[points.length - 1]));` which we need to pass few parameters. Here **polypoints** is the confused one, which i passed few static values. If possible can you look around see, that will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: yes the problem is with those static variables you passed in.
see what i did here
http://jsfiddle.net/bbxvhx17/185/


i got the points of the actual element. (d3 allows you to actually select elements, but i couldnt remember the syntax). also down in intersect polygon, subtract the width and the height, not half the width and half the height. 

Note this isnt my strong suit, i used a library to do the layout/edge routing for me.

Comment: Thanks you for your effort, arrow is still inside the polygon, but i got your point, i will try to solve it.

Comment: @Sam Do you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @BogdanTushevskyi No solution till now.